# Php Date : evaluate -1 days

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

I have something like an event in my project whose start date is stored in the database.
I want to advertise about the event a day before the event is going to start and during the days the event is active:

so i did

```
<?php $today = date('Y-m-d');
   $event_start_date = $event->event_start_date;
   $event_valid_advertise_date = strtotime ( '-1 day' , strtotime ( $event_start_date ) ) ;
   $event_valid_advertise_date = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $event_valid_advertise_date );
 ?>
```

I'm stuck now; I'm working with `codeigniter` and the database part is okay, but I just want to know how to subtract **$today** and **$event_start_date** to determine the valid period for advertisement.

PHP function `date_diff($today,$event_valid_date)` gives me an error saying:

`arg 1 should be of type date , string provided`

Comment: `date( 'Y-m-d' , ($event_start_date - 86400) );` ?

Comment: yes use date( 'Y-m-d' ) and strtotime() before date_diff() .. for both date ..

Comment: @BhavinRana i already have , if you see , $today and $ event_valid_advertise_date both use date('Y-m-d')

Comment: (int) [mktime](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) — Get Unix timestamp for a date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This will solve your problem above:**

```
$now = strtotime("now");
$event_advertise_date = strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($event->event_start_date));
if ($now > $event_advertise_date)
{
    echo "show event";
}
else
{
    echo "too early for this event";
}
```

**Reading your question - you can also use this improved code to stop showing the event after it is completed (I've made some assumptions - but you get the idea):**

```
$now = strtotime("now");
$event_advertise_date = strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($event->event_start_date));
$event_end_date = strtotime($event->event_end_date);
if (($now > $event_advertise_date) && ($now < $event_end_date))
{
    echo "show event";
}
else
{
    echo "too early or late for this event";
}
```

Comment: @user1537158 - Just a small suggestion: instead of two calls to `strtotime`, you can simply do this: `strtotime("{$event->event_start_date} -1 day");`.